# how to assign post to users in Hapijs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

how to associate post with the particular user or logged in user.
this is mongoose schema for post`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postModel = new Schema({
    title:{type: String,required: true},
    text:{type: String},
    comments:[{text:String},
    }],
    like: Boolean,
    validated: Boolean
});

module.exports= mongoose.model('Post',postModel);
```

`

this post goes to mongo database and then validated by admin.any user can comment or like the post.
please help how to achieve this functionality in hapijs

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to relationate models between documents in *mongodb*, and aren't strictly related with *hapijs*.

You can choose between embed posts into the user (I think is not a good solution in your case):

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/applications/data-models-relationships/

Or add a "foreing key" in the User or in Post side (better) to achieve it. 
With Mongoose ODM you have a "native" way to do it using populate feature:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
var aaron = new User({ name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

aaron.save(err => {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  var post = new Post({
    title: "Once upon a timex.",
    _creator: aaron._id    // assign the _id from the person
  });

  post.save(err => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // thats it!
  });
});
```